# How to change data to binary in R and keep the row names column?

Tags: r, dataframe, binary

I have a data frame that looks like this

```
Site <- c("X1","X2","X3","X4","X5","X6","X7","X8","X9","X10")
A <- c(0,0,1,2,4,5,6,7,13,56)
B <- c(1,0,0,0,0,4,5,7,7,8)
C <- c(2,3,0,0,4,5,67,8,43,21)
D <- c(134,0,0,2,0,0,9,0,45,55)
mydata <- data.frame(Site,A,B,C,D,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I want to convert all values > 0 to be 1 (i.e. binary), without jeopardising the column and row names.

I have tried `mydata[mydata>=1]<-1` but it also changed my first column (the row names) to 1 as well:

```
 head(mydata)
  Site A B C D
1    1 0 1 1 1
2    1 0 0 1 0
3    1 1 0 0 0
4    1 1 0 0 1
5    1 1 0 1 0
6    1 1 1 1 0
```

So how do I change just the values to binary, not the row names?

Comment: Converting to binary isnt just converting >=1 to 1, its also converting <1 to 0. Your example doesn't change negative numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can create a logical matrix and coerce to binary

```
mydata[-1] <- +(mydata[-1] > 0)
```

Comment: Note this isn't the same as **"convert all values > 0 to be 1"**, since it also converts any values <1 t o 0. It may be the questioner wants numbers less than 1, ie 0 **and negative numbers**, left alone, or that 0 is the lowest possible number (because maybe its count data) and that logical reassignment like this is acceptable.

Comment: @Spacedman yes, sorry I should have said in the question. My data is count data so it doesn't have negative values

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @akrun. It's very concise and handy!

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to the answer given by @akrun (+1), we can also try using `sapply()` to logically convert any non-zero number to `1` or else `0`:

```
mydata[-1] <- sapply(mydata[-1], function(x) { as.numeric(x > 0) })
mydata
   Site A B C D
1    X1 0 1 1 1
2    X2 0 0 1 0
3    X3 1 0 0 0
4    X4 1 0 0 1
5    X5 1 0 1 0
6    X6 1 1 1 0
7    X7 1 1 1 1
8    X8 1 1 1 0
9    X9 1 1 1 1
10  X10 1 1 1 1
```

If we weren't sure about the relative positioning of the columns, we could also address the numeric columns using `mydata[c("A", "B", "C", "D")]` or something similar.

Comment: Thank you very much. The relative positioning of the columns is known, and my real data has 5000 columns so I don't think addressing their names would be a good idea. Your answer works very well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try this which disregards if the number is negative or positive:

```
mydata[-1] <- (!is.na(mydata[-1]/mydata[-1]))*1
```

Answer (score 0):

`ifelse` function allows you to assign a new data if the value agrees or not your condition. Works for vectors but data frames also. I bind the Site column with the transformed ones.

`myBinData <- data.frame(Site = mydata$Site, ifelse(mydata[, -1] == 0, 0, 1))`

`Site A B C D
1    X1 0 1 1 1
2    X2 0 0 1 0
3    X3 1 0 0 0
4    X4 1 0 0 1
5    X5 1 0 1 0
6    X6 1 1 1 0
7    X7 1 1 1 1
8    X8 1 1 1 0
9    X9 1 1 1 1
10  X10 1 1 1 1`

Comment: Can you add some explanation for your answer?

Comment: hmm, this is what I don't want, since the first column is also transformed into 1s

Comment: @thanksd The function `ìfelse` allow you assign a value in the case in a value has or not some condition. Apply for vectors or data frames.

Comment: @gonzalez.ivan90, sorry should have clarified: Can you please edit your answer to include an explanation of the code? It'll be helpful for people finding your answer in the future.